# Referencing model in another model is displaying id and object instead of name. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, django

I have made two models. One of which references another. Here is my first model:
[image]

Here is my second model.py.
[image]

(I know it is weird).

This is what I get.

[image]

I have tried using:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.employee
```

Abd I have tried using:

```
def __str__(self):
            return self.employee.employee_name
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix this. I have also set `employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=CASCADE)` to see if that would make a difference. I knew it wouldn't. >:(

I honestly have never referenced another Model into another one before so I am a newbie at this. Any suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "this is what I get" and show the output, what is the exact context of that output?  Is it the result of a `print()` statement?  Is it displayed in the admin web interface?

Comment: It is the output displayed on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print employee name when printing Employee object (directly or via UserTiemsheet Object), you should override Employee class str method.

Sample Code

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
    return self.employee_name
```

Comment: So I should incorporate both models into one view?

Comment: Nope, you can define view anywhere. just you need to define str dunder method to get the string instead of object

Comment: I did though. But since I’m referencing another model it appears to not be working. If you look at the second picture I posted, I defined str under the model, but it is still showing “Employee Object(1)”. The second model is referencing the first one. Do I need to define the string in the first model and not the one that is being referenced in second model?

Comment: Yes you should define the str dunder method in first model i.e. Employee